# Limiting AC current

Tags: voltage, current, ac, transformer

I am looking for a way to limit AC current.

The application I have is used to remove the heat tint on stainless steel caused by welding (the blue-ish discoloration). Removing the tint is achieved by applying AC voltage through a conductive carbon bristle brush which is soaked with a phosphoric acid solution. Current flows through the brush and solution to the steel, which is clamped to 0v. The electrons flowing through the solution causes a reaction to take place which removes the heat tint stain.

Electrically, the existing device I'm using at the moment is very basic and coarse in design. It uses a 115 VAC to 14 VAC 200 VA transformer as the power source. The primary is not fused, the secondary has a re-settable 6-amp circuit breaker. During use, I've observed the current vary widely, often exceeding 10 amps. The current draw rises if the brush is pressed harder because the carbon bristles to fan out, creating a larger contact area for more current to flow through. This causes the circuit breaker to trip often, which is a nuisance I'd like to eliminate. I'm looking for a way to limit the current to 6 or 8 amps, with voltage drop not being an issue or concern.

Comment: You will need some current-sensing feedback and an active element to drop the voltage once the current is exceeding the given one. It's a control circuit, not a simple component. Unless you are OK with wasting power on a series resistance.

Comment: Inductor ballast or light bulb ballast in series.

Comment: Have you considered using a slower breaker? Likely it's very short peaks tripping it now, a slower breaker isn't as easily impressed by those.

Comment: @Mast I'd guess there is a risk to damage the steel and/or the brush if the high current is sustained for too long.

Answer (score 14):

Consider adding an automotive light bulb in series. Something like a 5.75" '12 Volt' round headlight bulb (high+low beam both connected) would be about right. They are about 100W total (7A or so) and designed to operate from about 14V continuously so they should last forever in this service.

[image: http://www.retroclassiccarparts.com/5-3-4-sealed-beam-60w-37-5w-12-volt]

As a bonus, the light will indicate when you are current limiting. I still have a beater that uses these things so I know they are still available but getting a bit rareish.

The connections at the back look, as far as I can recall, like regular 1/4" (6.35mm) fastons but if not they are solderable brass. Or grab the bulb and snip the connector from the nearest automotive junkyard.

The bulb is a highly **non-linear** resistance so during normal operation the voltage drop will be very low, and most of the voltage appears across the brush and surface you are working on. If you short it or come close to a short, then the bulb filament temperature increases and the resistance will increase by an order of magnitude or so, so the circuit is protected.

Edit: SAE drawing with connections shown from [this](https://law.resource.org/pub/us/cfr/ibr/005/sae.j1383.1985/sae.j1383.1985_014_01.jpg) source (connect the upper and lower filament terminals together).

[image]

Comment: Buy your stock of filament bulbs for this service before they all go LED!

Comment: @Neil_UK They went from sealed beam lamps to halogen sealed beam (same glass dimensions), then housing type conversions to halogen H4 filament bulbs, and then conversions to HID xenon with ballasts, and now conversions to LED.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps a cleaner solution (but more difficult to implement) is to use a transformer with a magnetic shunt. Such transformers can be salvaged from [welding equipment](http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Workshop/advice/coils/leak/weld/index.html). They limit the current by diverting some of the magnetic flux created by the primary winding away from the secondary, so the primary current is limited even when the secondary winding is short. In most such transformers, the shunt position can be adjusted, thus defining the current limit.

The use of such a transformer will eliminate the need for the secondary winding protection, as well as ballast.

BTW, if you decide to use ballast, it might be cheaper to put a mains-rated lightbulb in series with the primary winding, again leaving the secondary without any ballast or protection.

Comment: Clarify please? A shunted transformer will limit current on the primary? Does that affect the secondary current as well? I'm trying to limit the primary side of a welding transformer to 20A while letting the secondary be fairly high (in the hundreds). How does the amperes/volts calculation change when the transformer primary is shunted? Without shunts you calculate the resistance of the secondary and multiply it by the inverse transformer ratio, which could lead to a higher-than-desired primary current if the secondary is shorted.